# Removing checks that are only necessary on first pass

Tags: c#, unity3d

I've got a function that's executed in a game loop. There are a couple of checks that are really only necessary during the first pass of the game loop. How can I remove these? There is more code like this, but this is the shortest example.

```
public void Update(Frame rawBodyData)
{
    //Catch the first pass, where RawBody and FilteredBody are null
    //I'd like to remove this check
    if (RawBody.IsNull())
    {
        RawBody = rawBodyData;
    }
    //And this check
    if (FilteredBody.IsNull())
    {
        FilteredBody = rawBodyData;
    }

    _partiallyFilteredBody = rawBodyData;

    foreach (var filter in Filters)
    {
        //Check is a certain flag is set
        if ((_filterMethods & filter.Key) != 0)
        {
            _partiallyFilteredBody = filter.Value.Filter(_partiallyFilteredBody, FilteredBody);
        }
    }

    FilteredBody = _partiallyFilteredBody;
    RawBody = rawBodyData;
}
```

Other comments are certainly welcome. This is supposed to be high performance code, so I'd like to avoid things like LINQ (which ReSharper is already suggesting).

Comment: Can you please clarify which checks you'd like to remove?

Comment: @RubberDuck I thought the comment in the code might have clarified that. I'll make it clearer. I was talking about the first two checks, on `RawBody` and `FilteredBody`.

Comment: I thought so, but wanted to be certain.

Comment: Can you clarify how this `Update()` method is called? From one place or multiple? What is it used like?

Comment: @JeroenVannevel It is called once per frame, from a single place. It takes data from a Kinect sensor and processes the data. This data is provided to other object via FilteredBody and RawBody.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can remove the check for `RawBody.IsNull()` because you don't **read** the value of `RawBody` inside this method. If at the other places where some similiar code is called the `rawBody` is read, I would suggest to extract this check to a separate method and setting a flag which indicates that the check is already done. Like

```
private bool _bodyValueIsAssigned = false;
private void AssignValueIfNotAssigned(Frame frame)
{
    if (_bodyValueIsAssigned) { return; }

    if (RawBody.IsNull())
    {
        RawBody = frame;
    }

    if (FilteredBody.IsNull())
    {
        FilteredBody = frame;
    }

    _bodyValueIsAssigned  = true;
}
```

This can be called for the point where you call the `Update()` method. Without seeing more about how this is called (from an event or something similiar) there can't be said more.

---

If `Filters` is a `List<T>` or an array you should use performance wise a `for` loop instead of a `foreach`. See: https://stackoverflow.com/a/365658